# jQuery function audioElement ended doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got some code which creates an < audio > element and plays a song, when I click on a button. So far so good. The button turns from "Play Music" into "Stop Music" as it's clicked.

Now I added this code:

```
audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    $('span#pause').fadeOut('slow');
    $('span#play').delay(1500).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Which technically should show the Play-Button again, when the song is over. But it doesn't. Could anybody tell my why?

Here's the whole code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var songList = [
    'song1.ogg',
    'song2.ogg',
    'song3.ogg'
];
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*songList.length);

var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', songList[randomNumber]);
audioElement.load();

audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    $('span#pause').fadeOut('slow');
    $('span#play').delay(1500).fadeIn('slow');
});

$('#play').click(function() {
    audioElement.play();
    $('span#play').fadeOut('slow');
    $('span#pause').delay(1500).fadeIn('slow');
});

$('#pause').click(function() {
    audioElement.pause();
    $('span#pause').fadeOut('slow');
    $('span#play').delay(1500).fadeIn('slow');
});
});
```

Comment: Can't find a problem (with firefox 6). See my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DN8wT/14/).

Comment: somehow now it works for me too... reaally awkard. do you now now how I could start the next song?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question in your comment to start the next song: change the `src`-attribute of the `audio` tag. E.g. add a new `button` called "next" and following script:

```
$('#next').click(function() {
    randomNumber = (randomNumber + 1) % songList.length;
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', songList[randomNumber]);
    $('#play').click();
});
```

Also see the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DN8wT/16/).

=== UPDATE ===

- First the `randonNumber` will be incremented. The [modulo `%`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) (remainder of division) prevents, that the number is higher then the number of songs.
- Then the source of the `audio` tag will be set to the next song.
- At least a [`click` event will be triggered](http://api.jquery.com/click/), like somebody had clicked on the `play button`, so the `play click handler` starts the song and changes the `button` visibility.

Comment: Thanks for that. Could you please explain me what exactly happens there?